# question about release the object

Tags: objective-c

I create a object in a function.

```
-(void) loginAction {
    UILoginXML *loginXml = [[UILoginXML alloc] init];
    [loginXml start];
    [loginXml release];   //mark
}
```

when the start method was called, it may cost 2 or 3 minutes to parse XML.
the question is whether I can release this object at "mark"?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends, is `[loinXml start];` a synchronous call? Then it should work just fine, if it's asynchronous it will not.

If it costs you 2-3 minutes to parse, maybe its better to wrap ULoginXML to a class that has this current class as its delegate. Why? Then you can perform the parsing in the background and then send a message back to the delegate when you are done.

If you already parse in a background thread (ULoginXML), then you'll gain `loose coupling`, and `scaleability`.